# Multiple Client Certificates in SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile

Tags: ssl, apache-2.4, mod-proxy, proxypass

Here is my use case.

I want to learn how to setup `Apache`, so this is just for learning. Feel free to suggest better alternatives. I'm using `Apache 2.4` in `RHEL5`. I want to use a [ProxyPassMatch](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html) to proxy to two different sites

```
ProxyPassMatch "^/(a|b)/(*.jpg)$" https://$1.example.com/$2
```

But `a.example.com` and `b.example.com` requires different client certificates. I added

```
SSLProxyEngine on
SSLProxyMachineCertificateFile /path/certs/webs.pem
```

If the content of `webs.pem` is only one pair (certificate and private key) it works fine to connect to the correct site. But if I add the second pair (certificate and private key) it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslproxymachinecertificatefile) says:

```
Currently there is no support for encrypted private keys
```

Are you shure about that?

As workaround I would advise to use *SSLProxyMachineCertificatePath*. It is more flexible anyway. The constraints regarding encrypted keys still applies.